# Android: How to check email at a specific time with AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I need to print all my incoming email at 9AM every morning. Here is what I tried

The email part works fine. I am able to connect to email and print them all. The problem comes when I introduce the Alarm Manager. When I run it, nothing happens. It just hangs

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.job.JobInfo;
import android.app.job.JobScheduler;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.mail.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void checkEmail(View view) {
        Log.d("test", "accessing gmail");

        Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));


        // create an Intent 
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intentAlarm, 0);

        // create the object
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //set the alarm for 9 AM 
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 5, pi);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled for 9 AM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email Checker"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="152dp"
        android:onClick="checkEmail"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**AlarmReceiver.java (UPDATED CLASS)**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
         Intent i = new Intent(context, AsyncTaskActvity.class);
    i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
    context.startService(i);
        Log.d("test", "async");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

**AsyncTaskActvity.java**

```
package com.example.admin.myapplication;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class AsyncTaskActvity extends AsyncTask {


    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        computerUp();

        return null;


    }

    protected boolean computerUp () {



        try {

            Properties props = java.lang.System.getProperties();
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
            Session s = Session.getInstance(props);


            Message[] msgs;


            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            msgs = inbox.getMessages();

            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i].getSubject();
                Log.d("test", msgs[i].getSubject());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return true;
    }


}
```

When I run it, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please, read my answer. You have got a lot of errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you want to launch some code inside Android device you have to use this:

1. `AlarmManager` which launches `BroadcastReceiver`
2. use `WakeupBroadcastReceiver` to wake up your device.
3. Use stay-in-wakeup state of Android device while executing the code.
4. Do not forget to recharge after restarting your device.
5. YOU HAVE A PROBLEM WHILE STARTING ASYNCTASK !!!
6. You have incorrect  `alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 5, pi);` implementation. this string mean:"execute my code each 5 seconds. Start it is now!". This is not 9AM time;)

So, try this:

1. To charge `AlarmManager` at specific time:

> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent(BRWakeup.INTENT_FILTER) ;
>
>         PendingIntent pi =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, intentalarm, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
>         int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
>         if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
>           am.set(wakeup?AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP:AlarmManager.RTC, nexttime, pi);
>         } else if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
>           if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
>               am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexttime, pi);
>           } else {
>                   am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nexttime, pi);
>           }
>         }
> ```

where `ctx` - current `Context` class (parent Class for `Activity` and `Service`). For example, in `Activity` class this is `getContext()` or `getActivity()`. `nexttime` - time to lauch the receiver. For example, `long nexttime = System.getCurrentTimeMillis();`, `AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);` , `intentalarm` - is a some unique number to detect this launch event in future. It may be any number your want but the constant in your app. For example, `final int intentalarm = 22344;`

2. To launch service from `BroadcastReceiver`:

> ```
> public class BRWakeup extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
>   public static final String INTENT_FILTER = "com.example.BRWakeup";
>   @Override
>   public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>       OWakeLocker.acquire(ctx, 0);
>       ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(ctx.getPackageName(),
>                 SService.class.getName());
>       startWakefulService(ctx, intent.setComponent(comp));
>   }
>
> }
> ```

3. `OWakeLocker` is my own class which stores all launched services to save their lifes.

> ```
> public class OWakeLocker {
>     private static PowerManager.WakeLock[] wakeLocks = new PowerManager.WakeLock[1];//Services count
>
>     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
>   public static void acquire(Context ctx, int index) {
>       WakeLock wakeLock = wakeLocks[index];
>         if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();
>
>         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
>           wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
>                   PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
>                   PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, _.APPNAME + Integer.toString(index));
>         if (wakeLock != null && wakeLock.isHeld()){
>           wakeLock.acquire();
>         }
>     }
>
>     public static void release(int index) {
>       WakeLock wakeLock = wakeLocks[index];
>         if (wakeLock != null) 
>           wakeLock.release();
>           wakeLock = null;
>     }
> }
> ```

4. Use this service to execute your code:

> ```
> public class SService extends Service {
>
> @Override
>     public void onCreate() {
>       OWakeLocker.acquire(this, 0);
>       super.onCreate();
> }
> @Override
>   public void onDestroy() {
>       super.onDestroy();
>       OWakeLocker.release(_.indexNOTS_TAT);
>   }
> @Override
>   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
>       //your code to start AsyncTask
>
> AsyncTaskActvity atask = new AsyncTaskActvity();
>     atsk.execute();
> }
> }
> ```

5. To calculate good 9AM time you have to use this code:
   time and date for this calendar

> ```
>      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
> boolean iftoday = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 9;
>
> //to set the time as exact
>         cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
>         cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
>         cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
>         cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
>
>         if (!iftoday) {
>            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  
>         }
>         long nexttime = cal.getTimeInMillis();//this is the correct next time.
> ```

6. Use `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` instead of `setRepeating...` . And recharge `AlarmManager` at `SService.onDestroy()` method using the same code as in the `Activity`
7. Edit `AndroidManifest.xml`

> ```
> <receiver android:name="com.example.BRWakeup"
>           android:exported="false">
>           <intent-filter>
>               <action android:name="com.example.BRWakeup"/>
>           </intent-filter>
>       </receiver>
> <service android:name="com.example.SService"></service>
> ```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please post full code for these variables: `am`. `intentalarm`, nexttime, `ctx` thery are not initiated anywhere . Where  are they coming from

Answer (score 3):

Use Intent-Service with Broadcast Receiver.

Follow below link with example :

[Background Service](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services)

```
  public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;
   public static final String ACTION = "com.codepath.example.servicesdemo.alarm";
 // Triggered by the Alarm periodically (starts the service to run task)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Intent i = new Intent(context, MyTestService.class);
     i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
     context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. i tried this too.   `Intent i = new Intent(context, AsyncTaskActvity.class);       i.putExtra("foo", "bar");       context.startService(i);` Still the same result. Nothing happens

Comment: please update your question with changes in your code so i will be able to check, also provide manifest code

Comment: I updated AlarmReceiver.java **but it still doesn't work**

Answer (score 3):

First of all, change your code in the `checkEmail()` method to:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void checkEmail(View view) {
    Log.d("test", "accessing gmail");
    //set the current time and date for this calendar
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

    // create an Intent
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentAlarm, 0);

    // create the object
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    //set the alarm for 9 AM 
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled for 9 AM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

In `AlarmReceiver.java` class (make sure that this receiver already registered in manifest with custom action in `intent-filter` tag):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     new AsyncTaskActvity().execute();
     Log.d("test", "async");
     Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The main problem why you get the error is, you called `startService()` to a class that does not extend `Service`, i.e. `AsyncTaskActvity`. You need to find the difference between [Service](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm) and [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).